# In such a way vs in a position vs with

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. Put the cube into the bucket with the lower edge 2 cm below the water.

> 2. Put the cube into the bucket in such a way that the lower edge is 2cm below the water.

> 3. Put the cube into the bucket in a position where the lower edge is 2cm below the water.

I try to say that there is a bucket filled with water and a cube will be put into it. After putting it the lower edge of the cubewill be 2cm below the water . Which sentence would be more natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two sentences are natural. The third is not.

The first would more likely be used in a situation where it was trivially simple to do.

The second would more likely be used in a situation where it would require some thought or care to achieve.